# Using PageControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I have an array and lets say I have 5 objects in it. The array just contains a string with an address to a picture. I would like to use the Page Control feature in the iPhone SDK to swipe Left and Right to change the picture. I already have the multitouch gestures in place all I need is to implement the Page Control so if I swipe left and then right it will take me back to the previous image.

Does anyone know of any good Page Control tutorials or sample code online that may be able to help me thought implementing the Page Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIPageControl isn't a control as much as it's just an indication of what "page" your on.

To do what you want, you need to set up a UIScrollView and add subviews for each image. It will require some math to figure out where each "page" starts and ends based on image dimensions and screen sizes.

Apple has some docs on using scroll views with page controls [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH3-SW1).

Comment: That worked for me. Thank You!

Quick Question? Is there a way to set the maximum amount of page in a PageControl? For Example I could set the Current Page.

Comment: Check the docs. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need a `UIScrollView` along with the `UIPageControl`. You can find a good tutorial on how to make them work together [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)